# Webpack aot build fails searching for ngfactory Files

Tags: javascript, angular

Following is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir":"./aot",
    "rootDir" : ".",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Using angular 6.0.3 and @ngtools/webpack 1.10.2

Same config was working with angular 5.1.0

Comment: How did you actually upgrade angular? Did you use `ng update`, or did you just change your package.json file to reference v6?

Comment: Maybe you will have better luck asking in angular's github issues section

Comment: No I didnt use ng update. I changed package.json manually.